# Overflow with multiplication of hex values

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

Puzzled with VBA behavior: `&H100 * &HBB` generates an overflow error (`Runtime Error '6' Overflow`), while `16 ^ 2 * 187` does not. Suspect it's data-type coercion with the `&H` literal character; just was cleaner to read in the code using hex notation (color settings). Would like to understand what's behind it, if you can shed some light!!

MS Word VBA (VBA7) on 64-bit Office365 license.

Comment: Page 26 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d5418146-0bd2-45eb-9c7a-fd9502722c74. This is the spec for writing a VBA compiler/interpreter. Note you have to pay license fees to do so (VBScript is free to implement in your programs). Hex is *unsigned* and yours are 16 bit. **But you haven't shown the whole statement**.

Comment: I should have added that I am nowhere near a professional programmer (just a hobbyist). I'm certainly not trying to write a compiler/interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `&H100` and `&HBB` default to *Integer* which cannot hold the expected result: `47872`.

However, `16 ^ 2` defaults to *Double* and then `187` as well, and *Double* can easily hold `47872`.

Convert to *Long* (or *Currency* or *Decimal*) when you expect larger integer results:

```vb
? CLng(&H100) * CLng(&HBB)
47872
```

Comment: You don't know that *It's because &H100 and &HBB default to Integer which cannot hold the expected result: 47872.* The partial statement needs more code. For instance it works assigned to a variant.

Comment: @Lundt: It does in the Immidiate pane, and that's what we have now.

Comment: You have `47872` which is a valid long. The code in the question does nothing and it's not valid code. Without the rest of the line, and any `Dim` statements related to it would have to be known.

Comment: @Lundt: It certainly is valid code. Feel free to copy/paste my code line which, from the context, is what the questioneer has puzzled with.

Comment: Since the calculation was throwing the error, one should be able to deduce that code was not written in a way that would work, and therefore the cause was as @Gustav explained. The information I desired was exactly that the &H defaults to Integer. Point of information to satisfy curiosity is that my code was defining a custom ENUM for consistent color values without having to know the RGB values.

Comment: Ancillary curiosity is why some color values in MSWord object model use BGR instead of RGB ... not to mention why hex values would be constrained to integer limitations!

Comment: *constrained to integer limitations* because that is what happened in 16 bit basic. It is about backward compatibility.